# Running jasmine from command line raises template error with es6 tests

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jasmine, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use jasmine-rails to run tests from the command line.  My tests are written in es6.  I have a spec called company_spec.es6 that I can run from the browser.

Whenever I run `rake spec:javascript` I get the following error:
`ActionView::Template::Error: couldn't find file 'models/company_spec.es6' with type 'application/javascript'`

I read through the documentation on the jasmine-rails repo and my jasmine.yml has the following:

`spec_files:
  - '**/*[sS]pec.{js,es6}'`

What am I missing?  How can I get my tests running from command line?

Comment: Have you verified that your pathing is right?

Comment: It turned out to be a problem with how I had jasmine rails configured.  I switched to jasmine:ci and that works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to jasmine:ci and that has worked without any problems.

Comment: Can you add some more detail - what was it that you switched from? What is `jasmine:ci` and where should it be used?

Comment: @Nick, jasmine:ci is the built in jasmine rake task that comes with the jasmine-gem.  It uses phantomjs to run the tests.